# Image not showing in Chrome

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, google-chrome

I am attempting to set the source of an image. The image shows up correctly in IE and Firefox, but it doesn't show in Chrome. The error message that shows up in the console is: "Resource interpreted as image but transferred with MIME type text/html."

```
ColdFusion.Window.show('loading');
image = <cfoutput>#randrange(1,numImages)#</cfoutput>;
document.getElementById("loadImg").src = "./images/loading" + image + ".gif";           
setTimeout('document.images["loadImg"].src = "./images/loading" + image + ".gif"', 100);
```

I imagine I have to change the MIME type, but I have no idea how to go about doing this. What do I have to change for this to work in Chrome?

Comment: Can you show us the rest of your page (HTML and the like) or an example page? Does an error message show up on the console (shift+ctrl+J)?

Comment: Have you tried without the dot in the path?

Comment: There is an error message- see my edit above.

Comment: That error message usually means the URL in `src` is being redirected.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the error message describes the problem exactly. Apparently other browsers have less problems with an image served with an incorrect MIME type, but Chrome doesn't like it.

This is almost certainly a server side error. Are the images you want generated dynamically, like using a PHP script?

Answer (score 2):

I would use the Developer Tools (Ctrl-Shift-I) and examine the src attribute that you're assigning. Once you get that URL, give it a try to see if you're actually getting an image. As others have said, you may be getting a 404. The URL may not be formed exactly as you intend.

Answer (score 2):

**IF** you know that the image exists at that location then the webserver's mime-types are likely mis-configured for .gif. Should be image/gif looks like it is text/html.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the text/html mime type is because the image URL is returning a 404 page. Try it without the dot in the path:

```
document.getElementById("loadImg").src = "images/loading" + image + ".gif";
```

Comment: Well, I'm thinking that chrome is interpreting the URL as something like http://foo.com/./images/loading1.gif, and the webserver is returning a 404 page. Chrome then throws the error because the HTML that comes back is not image data.

Comment: But every webserver (or Chrome itself) should simply resolve that URL to foo.com/images/loading1.gif. I just tested this with Chrome using http://stackoverflow.com/./questions and Chrome automatically resolves the URL correctly.